# Test computed property in Vue.js using AVA with Avoriaz

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties, ava, avoriaz

I'm trying to test a computed property of a Vue.js component using AVA and Avoriaz. I can mount the component and access the data properties fine.

When I try an access a computed property, the function doesn't seem to have scope to the data on that component.

```js
computed: {
  canAdd() {
    return this.crew.firstName !== '' && this.crew.lastName !== '';
  }
```

The error I get is `Error: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined`

Test file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import { mount }
from 'avoriaz';
import test from 'ava';
import nextTick from 'p-immediate';
import ComputedPropTest from '../../../js/vue-components/computed_prop_test.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

test.only('Should handle computed properties', async(t) => {
  const MOCK_PROPS_DATA = {
      propsData: {
        forwardTo: '/crew',
        crew: {}
      }
    },
    wrapper = mount(ComputedPropTest, MOCK_PROPS_DATA),
    DATA = {
      crew: {
        firstName: 'Ryan',
        lastName: 'Gill'
      }
    };

  wrapper.setData(DATA);
  await nextTick();

  console.log('firstName: ', wrapper.data().crew.firstName); // Ryan

  console.log('isTrue: ', wrapper.computed().isTrue()); // true
  console.log('canAdd: ', wrapper.computed().canAdd()); // Errors

  t.true(wrapper.computed().isTrue());
});
```

Component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <label for="firstName" class="usa-color-text-primary">First Name
      <i class="tooltipTextIcon fa fa-info-circle usa-color-text-gray" title="First name of crew."></i>
      <span class="required usa-additional_text usa-color-text-secondary-dark">Required</span>
    </label>
    <input id="firstName" type="text" class="requiredInput" name="firstName" v-model="crew.firstName" autofocus>
    <label for="lastName" class="usa-color-text-primary">Last Name
      <i class="tooltipTextIcon fa fa-info-circle usa-color-text-gray" title="Last name of crew."></i>
      <span class="required usa-additional_text usa-color-text-secondary-dark">Required</span>
    </label>
    <input id="lastName" type="text" class="requiredInput" name="lastName" v-model="crew.lastName" autofocus>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'crew-inputs',
    data() {
      return {
        crew: {
          firstName: '',
          lastName: ''
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      canAdd() {
        return this.crew.firstName !== '' && this.crew.lastName !== '';
      },
      isTrue() {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `isTrue` computed property seems to work but doesn't rely on any of the data in the component.

Comment: @Eliran Malka, your "reformatting" made code less readable. What was the problem with 2 white spaces for a tab and  comma-first array? Please revert the change, ty.

Comment: I see you've added console logs accessing the data and computed properties of the component you are testing. Are they reporting what you expect them to? It is recommended that you add comments above/next to the logs describing the actual result and the expected result as opposed to leaving them uncommented.

Comment: @wing yea, the logs are as expected. I just updated the question with the values of the logs as comments. Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to add breakpoints and inspect the scope? What does this yield? Does the computed method work as expected outside a test environment?

Comment: Seems like it works without using `Avoriaz`

`let comp = new Vue(ComputedPropTest, MOCK_PROPS_DATA).$mount();
  comp.crew = DATA;
  console.log(comp.canAdd);`

Comment: @wing not sure on adding a breakpoint but if I log out `this` inside the component's computed property, it returns an empty object `{}`.

Comment: That suggests to me that the wrong `this` is being bound to the computed getter. Do you know if the code is being run with a `'use-strict'` pragma?

Comment: @wing yes it running in strict mode but possible issues with the fat arrows?

Comment: I don't believe arrow functions are preventing `this` being bound correctly. You _could_ attempt to change some arrow functions but I doubt it'll work. Is your test code running in the browser? You're using Ava so I am assuming it isn't. My suspicion is that not running Avoriaz in the browser is causing issues: I've run a reduced test case in the browser and in a non-browser environment. The browser passes while the non-browser environment fails – although I'm still looking into what exactly is happening and why.

Comment: Update on the environment theory: I think I'm ruling it out. I think Avoriaz is influencing the binding of `this` to something that you don't want.

Comment: Hi Ryan, sorry you're having problems with avoriaz. If you make an issue on https://github.com/eddyerburgh/avoriaz/issues I'll work on a fix this weekend and notify you when it's done. If you don't have time, I'll write it up myself and get it fixed within a week :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem

### What is happening?

After a long look and discussion, it looks like the `this` context of the computed getter is being set to something unexpected. As a result of the unexpected `this` context, `this` no longer refers to the Vue instance, leading to component properties being unaccessible.

You are witnessing this with the runtime error

> `Error: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined`

### Why is this happening?

Without a deep dive into how Avoriaz and Vue are working, we cannot know. I did attempt a deeper investigation with the following minimal, complete and verifiable example. You or others may want to take a deeper look into it.

```
'use-strict';

import Vue from 'vue';
import { mount } from 'avoriaz';

const FooBar = {
  template: `
    <div>{{ foobar }}</div>
  `,

  data() {
    return {
      foo: 'foo',
      bar: 'bar',
    };
  },

  computed: {
    foobar() {
      debugger;
      return `${this.foo} ${this.bar}`;
    },
  },
};

const vueMountedCt = new Vue(FooBar).$mount();
const vueMountedVm = vueMountedCt;

const avoriazMountedCt = mount(FooBar);
const avoriazMountedVm = avoriazMountedCt.vm;

/**
 * Control case, accessing component computed property in the usual way as documented by Vue.
 *
 * @see {@link https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html}
 *
 * Expectation from log: 'foobar' (the result of the computed property)
 * Actual result from log: 'foobar'
 */
console.log(vueMountedVm.foobar);

/**
 * Reproduce Avoriaz's method of accessing a Vue component's computed properties.
 * Avoriaz returns the Vue instance's `$option.computed` when calling `wrapper.computed()`.
 *
 * @see {@link https://github.com/eddyerburgh/avoriaz/blob/9882f286e7476cd51fe069946fee23dcb2c4a3e3/src/Wrapper.js#L50}
 *
 * Expectation from log: 'foobar' (the result of the computed property)
 * Actual result from log: 'undefined undefined'
 */
console.log(vueMountedVm.$options.computed.foobar());

/**
 * Access Vue component computed property via Avoriaz's documented method.
 *
 * @see {@link https://eddyerburgh.gitbooks.io/avoriaz/content/api/mount/computed.html}
 *
 * Expectation from log: 'foobar' (the result of the computed property)
 * Actual result from log: 'undefined undefined'
 */
console.log(avoriazMountedCt.computed().foobar());
```

Some observations:

- Looking at the call stack of control case (case 1), you can see Vue's internals setting the `this` context to the Vue instance.

[image: Call stack of case 1. Getter function's <code>this</code> is being set to Vue instance]

- Looking at the call stack of the failing cases, the `this` context of the computed function is not being set.

[image: Call stack of failing cases. The <code>this</code> context of the computed function is not being set]

As to why this is happening – I have no idea. To understand this I think we will need to know why `vm.$options.computed` exists, the planned use cases from the core Vue team and if the behaviour we are experiencing is expected.

## What can I do about this?

You can work around this by doing

```
wrapper.computed().canAdd.call(wrapper.vm);
```

It may also be recommended you open issues in [Avoriaz](https://github.com/eddyerburgh/avoriaz/issues) and/or [Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues).

Comment: Hi, thanks for this detailed answer. I'm the author of avoriaz and am keen to fix bugs this bug for the next release

Comment: @Edd: no worries. I'm not familiar with Avoriaz or Vue's internals so this report is just my observation and comment on what I believe is happening. Hopefully it'll help you in getting this resolved. One potential path to look down is seeing what `vm.$options.computed` is for – I suspect it may not be the place that reliably gives you computed properties, but I can't confirm the core team's position on this.

Comment: Good explanation. Computed properties are not easy to test.